# Prevent Chrome from redirecting to https on certain domains?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I am using Laravel valet to host websites on my local machine for dev using the *.app domain. Whenever I try to visit URL's using Chrome they get redirect to the https version (which i do not want). How can I alter this behaviour for my local websites?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the intended behavior since the Chrome 63 update took place. [This blog](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/) talks about .dev but this is also happening to .app apparently.

> tl;dr: Chrome 63 (out since December 2017), will force all domains
>   ending on .dev (and .foo) to be redirected to HTTPS via a preloaded
>   HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) header.
>
> This adds the following line to Chromium's preload lists;
>
> ```
> { "name": "dev", "include_subdomains": true, "mode": "force-https" },
> { "name": "foo", "include_subdomains": true, "mode": "force-https" },
> ```

Comment: Is there a way I can prevent it from forcing https on `.app` domains?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to prevent this behavior on Chrome, however it is possible for Firefox.
You have no choice than having an alternative solution.

Via this [article](https://tutoref.com/how-to-prevent-firefox-and-chrome-from-forcing-dev-and-foo-domains-to-use-https/):

1. In Firefox, visit about:config via the address bar
2. Search for the parameter network.stricttransportsecurity.preloadlist
3. Change it’s value to `false`